# Reference function from angular controller in html

Tags: angularjs, google-plus

I have a basic angular app with one controller.
Now, i am creating a signin with g+ button like this

```
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script');
  po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=renderSignin';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

the function 'renderSignin' is defined in my controller as follows

```
$scope.renderSignin = function() { ... }
```

But it looks like it can't be found. I also tried {{renderSignin}}, but it didn't work either
Is there something i have to do to get it to work?
Thanks.

Comment: I dont see any angular controller code here.. can you add some more context?

Comment: And where is that Google Plus code running?

Comment: The angular code is kind of bulky, which is why i didn't put it up at first, but i find that attaching the function to $window as said by CD.. works perfectly, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `renderSignin` to the `$window` instead of the `$scope`.

```
$window.renderSignin = function() { ... }
```

(Don't forget injecting `$window` into your `controller`)